# Making RSA keys in Java

Tags: java, rsa

I am a rank amateur when it comes to Java. I need to use a java program to make an RSA public key. I have a script given to me by the perosn who wants the key, it looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
public class CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator{

 public void generate() {
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator objlRSAKeyPairGen =
        KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        objlRSAKeyPairGen.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair objlRSAKeyPair = objlRSAKeyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPublicKey objlPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) objlRSAKeyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey objlPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) objlRSAKeyPair.getPrivate();
        StringBuffer strblPublicKey = new StringBuffer();
        strblPublicKey.append(objlPublicKey.getModulus().toString(16).toUpperCase());
        strblPublicKey.append('~');
        strblPublicKey.append(objlPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toString(16).toUpperCase()
    ); 

    System.out.println(strblPublicKey.toString());
    StringBuffer strblPrivateKey = new StringBuffer();
    strblPrivateKey.append(objlPrivateKey.getModulus().toString(16).toUpperCase());
    strblPrivateKey.append('~');
    strblPrivateKey.append(objlPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent().toString(16).toUpperCase());

    System.out.println(strblPrivateKey.toString()); 

    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgrtm){
        System.out.println(noSuchAlgrtm.getMessage());
    }catch (NoSuchProviderException noSuchProvdr) { 
        System.out.println((noSuchProvdr.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

But when I run this I get:

CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.java:51: ')' expected
            System.out.println((noSuchProvdr.getMessage());
                                                          ^
1 error

I don't get what the problem is here. I'm so unfamiliar with java, what should I do next? Is this just a typo?

Comment: Why not ask the person who gave you the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the 4th from bottom line of code:

```
System.out.println((noSuchProvdr.getMessage());
                   ^
```

Remove the extra parenthesis from there to make it

```
System.out.println(noSuchProvdr.getMessage());
```

**Edit:** If the compiler is telling you `java.security.NoSuchProviderException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`, remove this last `catch` block

```
catch (NoSuchProviderException noSuchProvdr) { 
    System.out.println((noSuchProvdr.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Now I get CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.java:51: exception java.security.NoSuchProviderException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement: }catch (NoSuchProviderException noSuchProvdr) {

Comment: That means that the `NoSuchProviderException` does not need to be caught, and you should remove that entire `catch` block

Comment: Ah I was able to get it to compile but now I get "Exception in thread "main"" when I try to run it. I guess this is a different problem than the one I asked you about initially.

Answer (score 0):

Count the parens on that line.

Comment: Oh thank you I was looking at the wrong line. OK but now I get:CustomRSAKeyPairGenerator.java:51: exception java.security.NoSuchProviderException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement }catch (NoSuchProviderException noSuchProvdr) {

Comment: Then remove that `catch` clause.

Comment: dont you think, it should go it comment ?

Comment: No, because it is the answer to the question.